# Is there a correct way to publish from a complex SwingWorker task

Tags: recursion, publish, swingworker

My background task involves a recursive process such that the actual work is being done several removes from the SwingWorker task itself.  This process starts out by recursing through a folder structure, like this:

```
if ( inputFile.isDirectory ( ) )
{
    new FolderProcessor ( inputFile ).execute ( ... ) ;
}
else
{
    new FileProcessor ( inputFile , ... ).execute ( ... ) ;
}
```

Within FileProcessor there is another (more complex) recursive process that deals with the contents of the file, producing multiple output files from each input file.  I'd like to report progress back to the UI from within the lower-level recursive process.

Is there a correct way to handle this?  Before things evolved and became more complex, this project was able to handle everything within the top-level SwingWorker class and was able to report simply by using

```
publish("producing output file " + outputFileName + " from " + inputFileName) ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct answer is probably to implement the Observer pattern.  That is, pass "this" to any component tasks;

```
new ComponentTask ( ... , this ).execute ( ... ) ;
```

or

```
new ComponentTask ( ... ).execute ( ... , this ) ;
```

implement a method in the SwingWorker

```
public void sendProgress(final String text)
{ publish(text) ; }
```

Have the component tasks invoke sendProgress on the passed object to pass the information back to the UI.

Even if it's not "correct", it seems to work, and it feels right.